# href google fonts over https only if https page requested

Tags: javascript, https, href

I am using google fonts on webpage, but the font is being called over http -

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

If the page is requested over https - the fonts are identified as unsecure content.

How do I request

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css
```

only if the page is being requested over https connection, and serve http if http requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drop the `http:` which will make the url relative to the current scheme

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: does that not look on my server in the root?  Guess not.  Dont think I know my // & / & ../   Thanks

Comment: Worth noting that this working does depend on the target server having SSL support. Google Fonts does, and also changes URL references within the CSS files to use the appropriate URL. But this same technique won't necessarily work on any external resource you might happen to be using.